# Wrong order of processing with promise then function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

After a user sends a comment in my app I want to notify other user about that.
I use promise then function but the order of the execution is wrong. I did it like in this [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then). What is wrong here?

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

   exports.Push = functions.database.ref('/placeID/{groupID}/{messageID}/')
   .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
 
var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
       resolve(testen());

      });

p1.then(function(value) {
        pushsenden(); // Success!
      }, function(reason) {
      });



function testen (){
    const groupID = context.params.groupID;
    const messageID = context.params.messageID;
    var db = admin.database();
    var ref = db.ref('/placeID/'+groupID + '/' +messageID + '/');      
ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
  nameUser = snapshot.val().userName
  commentUser = snapshot.val().userComment
}, function (errorObject) {
});

}

function pushsenden (){
    var topic = 'weather';
    const payload = {
        notification: {
            title: 'Name of User',
            body: 'Content of User',
            badge: '1',
            sound: 'default'
        }
   };
   console.log('sending push notification');
   admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic,payload);
}
     })
```

[image]

Comment: `p1` will never resolve ... so that's a problem for a start - see how in the example `resolve` is called at the appropriate time

Comment: Like this now? I used resolve(testen());. But the issue is still the same.

Comment: Can you show me where in the tutorial they show this? I am new to Javascript. And I don't now what you mean with semblance of readability.

Comment: `resolve('Success!');` - but you want to do `resolve(testen())` which will immediately resolve to whatever that function returns (nothing, so it will resolve to undefined) - so your code wont "wait" for `testen()` to run, therefore you won't get the order you require - Promises are not magic, they don't inherently wait for asynchronous code to complete

Comment: ok but how can I define the return of the promise for the function tested()? The return contains two string not one like here with success.

Comment: I imagine code like [this](https://pastebin.com/fgv1YJL6) is what you want - note the total lack of `p1`

Comment: `The return contains two string` ... where? is `on("value"` called more than once? if so, you probably don't want to use promises like this at all

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by  Jaromanda X :

> resolve('Success!'); - but you want to do resolve(testen()) which will
> immediately resolve to whatever that function returns (nothing, so it
> will resolve to undefined) - so your code won't "wait" for testen() to
> run, therefore you won't get the order you require.

As mentioned in the [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions):

> When you return a JavaScript promise to a function, that function
> keeps running until the promise is resolved or rejected. To indicate
> that a function has completed its work successfully, the promise
> should be resolved. To indicate an error, the promise should be
> rejected. This means you only need to handle errors that you want to.
>
> The following code takes a Firebase Realtime Database ref and sets its
> value to "world!". By returning the result of set, your function is
> guaranteed to keep running until the asynchronous work of writing the
> string to the database is fully completed:
>
> ```
> // Always change the value of "/hello" to "world!"
> exports.hello = functions.database.ref('/hello').onWrite(event => {
>   // set() returns a promise. We keep the function alive by returning it.
>   return event.data.ref.set('world!').then(() => {
>     console.log('Write succeeded!');
>   });
> });
> ```

For reference, You can follow the [link](https://pastebin.com/fgv1YJL6) as mentioned by Jaromanda X

> ```
> const functions = require("firebase-functions");
> const admin = require("firebase-admin");
> admin.initializeApp();
>
> exports.Push = functions.database
>     .ref("/placeID/{groupID}/{messageID}/")
>     .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
>
>         testen().then(
>             function (value) {
>                 pushsenden(); // Success!
>             },
>             function (reason) {}
>         );
>
>         function testen() {
>             return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
>                 const groupID = context.params.groupID;
>                 const messageID = context.params.messageID;
>                 var db = admin.database();
>                 var ref = db.ref("/placeID/" + groupID + "/" + messageID + "/");
>                 ref.on(
>                     "value",
>                     function (snapshot) {
>                         nameUser = snapshot.val().userName;
>                         commentUser = snapshot.val().userComment;
>                         resolve();
>                     },
>                     function (errorObject) {
>                         reject(errorObject);
>                     }
>                 );
>             });
>         }
>
>         function pushsenden() {
>             var topic = "weather";
>             const payload = {
>                 notification: {
>                     title: "Name of User",
>                     body: "Content of User",
>                     badge: "1",
>                     sound: "default",
>                 },
>             };
>             console.log("sending push notification");
>             admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic, payload);
>         }
>     });
> ```

You can refer to the [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions#examples_in_context)   for the various examples which will be helpful to know more about Promises.

Comment: @submariner Posted an answer as community wiki, is it helpful?